Handling Field-Level Permissions in API Responses
I would like the API user to receive responses from the fields they have access to, and an error response for the rest. In the case of a directive, the entire query will return an error, even if the user has access to some fields. I know it is possible to implement the @include logic on the client side to skip certain fields in specific cases, but I would like to avoid this as it requires a lot of work (having to pass information to the client about what they have access to).
I’m considering a solution:
Would it be correct to use a union on a single field? Something like the example below:
{
  id {
    ... on Value {
      value
    }
    ... on PermissionError {
      message
    }
  }
}

Response when admin:
{
  id {
    value: "my_id"
  }
}

Response for other users:
{
  id {
    message: "You don't have permission to access this field"
  }
}


Your approach would probably require every field that can resolve to a PermissionError needing to be a union, which can be cumbersome. Instead i would recommend checking out if you cannot achieve what you want with Field errors, specifically with a partial result. There also is a section in the specification about that e.g. Handling Field Errors.
One disadvantage of this approach might be with nullability in the schema (see: GraphQL field level authorization and nullability)

Thank you for your response.
I understand this approach, but I'm not entirely convinced about using nulls in that way. It seems to me that null serves a different purpose, and the fewer nulls there are, the more readable the code becomes.
On the other hand, using union types might increase the complexity of queries and in some cases, it can either improve or reduce the readability of the API.
In my case, such use of union types won't be frequent, but it's hard to predict what the future holds.
